# How can I make something like "abc /help" work in batch?

Tags: batch-file, call

I have a file called *abc.bat*. I want it to do this code when on the command line, and in the same directory of abc.bat, I type in `abc /help`:

```
echo 2
```

And when it's just *abc.bat* or *abc* I type in there:

```
echo 96
```

How do I do this, so I can get a better understanding of batch?

Comment: As jeb pointed out below, you can access command line parameters from batch by using the built in variables %1, %2, %3, etc, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply check the argument against `/HELP`

Like

```
@echo off
if "%1"=="/help" goto :help

echo 96
exit /b

:help
echo This is the help
exit /b
```

Comment: Just pointing out that subsequent parameters can be accessed using %2, %3, %4 and so on.

Comment: You probably want to add the `/I` switch to your `IF` statement for case-insensitive comparison.

Comment: And if you use 2 times that same command except /help and goto :help is modified  then it just won't work.